# What's is best way to keep version of Java EE application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ear

What's is best way to keep version of java ee application (EAR) version. Moreover I would like to read version at runtime. 
I thought about keeping version in MANIFEST.MF (set during build). But reading MANIFEST.MF file is not so easy in java ee application.

Comment: How do you mange your project code? Ant, Maven, Gradle, ...?

Comment: Gradle. To build ear I use ear-plugin

Comment: *"not so easy"*, how so? What problem exactly did you face then? That would be the question of interest instead of the current subjectively formulated question.

Comment: @ostry sorry, I don't use gradle (yet), but I guess it has to be a similar mechanism as with maven. In maven I use project version property to be filtered (resources plugin) in a java properties file, from where I read project version.

Answer (score -2):

To add version to MANIFEST.MF with gradle EAR plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

ear {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            "ImplVersion": project.version
        )
    }
}
```

But EAR MANIFEST.MF file is not added to class-path. So the only option is to add the custom file version.